# Plot mean data for each group in facet wraps in R (show geom_smooth)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, facet-wrap

I have time series data of "Date","hour", "day", "weekdays", "Value".
I want to group the data in a way that it gives me plots of mean of Value for each weekday (Monday, Tueasday, etc.) but in a way that the mean is calculated for the certain day. For example in the plot Monday, the mean should be the average for all the Mondays in the dataest.

The data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(1482087600, 1482084000, 1482080400, 
1482076800, 1482073200, 1482069600, 1482066000, 1482062400, 1482058800, 
1482055200, 1482051600, 1482048000, 1482044400, 1482040800, 1482037200, 
1482033600, 1482030000, 1482026400, 1482022800, 1482019200, 1482015600, 
1482012000, 1482008400, 1482004800, 1482001200, 1481997600, 1481994000, 
1481990400, 1481986800, 1481983200, 1481979600, 1481976000, 1481972400, 
1481968800, 1481965200, 1481961600, 1481958000, 1481954400, 1481950800, 
1481947200, 1481943600, 1481940000, 1481936400, 1481932800, 1481929200, 
1481925600, 1481922000, 1481918400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), hour = c(23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 
15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 
1L, 0L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 
12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L), day = c(18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L), week = c(51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 
51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51, 51), weekdays = c("Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", "Sunday", 
"Sunday", "Sunday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", "Saturday", 
"Saturday", "Saturday"), Online_h = c(18L, 20L, 25L, 29L, 31L, 
32L, 30L, 23L, 24L, 17L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 12L, 
16L, 16L, 23L, 25L, 25L, 35L, 38L, 44L, 39L, 32L, 28L, 30L, 23L, 
22L, 21L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 12L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 14L, 21L, 
27L, 29L, 34L)), row.names = c(NA, 48L), class = "data.frame")
```

My current code looks like this:

```
df%>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  group_by(hour) %>%
  mutate(avg_hour = mean(Value)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=hour, y=avg_hour)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  ylab("Available drivers") + 
  xlab("Hours") +
  facet_wrap(vars(weekdays))
```

Which results this graph.

[image]

However, the mean line seems the same for all the days, while it should be different if it is calculated for each group of days. Could anyone help me to correctly find the means for each group and show it on the plots?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try `ggplot(aes(..., group = weekdays))`. Also, simplify to `group_by(day, hour)`

Comment: Yeah, the bug is in `group_by(hour)` which will (IIRC) replace the day grouping.

Comment: Okay, it helped, but after doing it I receive mean values which are higher than the macimum in the column, what can be the reason and why do I receive such data?

Comment: The dataset you posted has only one day of the week. Could you update it to include your full data (or a somewhat representative sample of your full data). Then we'll be able to help you more easily.

Comment: @KeneDavidNwosu I just updated the data in the question to include 2 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `group_by` calls should not be separated like that.

EDIT: I notice that you have only one hour per hour in the dataset so it is not clear what you want to find the mean of...

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(weekdays, hour) %>%
  mutate(avg_drivers_online_per_hour = mean(Online_h)) %>%
  group_by(weekdays) %>% 
  mutate(avg_drivers_online_per_weekday = mean(Online_h)) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=hour, y=avg_drivers_online_per_hour)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0, xend = 24, y = avg_drivers_online_per_weekday, yend = avg_drivers_online_per_weekday), color = "dodgerblue2") +
  ylab("Available drivers") + 
  xlab("Hours") +
  facet_wrap(vars(weekdays))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>